# Web Based SVN Tool

Tags: untagged

I am looking for a web solution where I can install it on my SVN server. I would like to be able to do the following with it:

1. Track changes by author
2. Create a report on who did what
3. View changes (diffs)
4. Hopefully would be open source and easy to install
5. Runs on Linux

Does such software exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) from Atlassian

It can connect to your repo and do all the things you asked

Comment: Have you tried it before? I keep hearing about that toolset. Do you like it?

Comment: I like it very much so.

Comment: Yes, use it extensively. Haven't tried Crucible yet as only in a 2 person team.

Answer (score 5):

The nicest I've seen  yet is [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/), I believe it has all the features you mentioned and it's open source.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), a light-weight web-based software project management system. It integrates well with SVN, has tickets, view source & timeline (history of commits). Just an option, of course.

Comment: +1 for Trac - it's what I use

Answer (score 0):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) should be ok.